# Select records ignoring null values with date between some range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want only those records where records must exist between particular dates. For e.g. if the date given is between 2013-7-1 AND 2013-7-17 and I've a entry in Purchase table dated: 2013-6-5 and a entry in Sale table dated 2013-7-17 for a particular product. It should ignore these rows and select only those rows where sale & purchase have occur in desired date range. My below query is not working properly. Because of the above defined situation divided by zero exception occurs. Kindly help me.

```
SELECT        o.Name AS Owner, c.Name AS Company, SUM(sq.PQuantity) - SUM(sq.SQuantity) AS Quantity, SUM(sq.PQuantity * sq.PRate) / SUM(sq.PQuantity) AS Rate, 
                             (SUM(sq.PQuantity) - SUM(sq.SQuantity)) * (SUM(sq.PQuantity * sq.PRate) / SUM(sq.PQuantity)) AS Amount,sq.CompanyId AS CompanyId, o.OwnerId AS OwnerId
    FROM            (SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, Quantity AS PQuantity, RatePerShare AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, Date
                              FROM            Purchase
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, Quantity AS PQuantity, 0 AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, Date
                              FROM            Bonus
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, Quantity AS PQuantity, CostOfShare AS PRate, 0 AS SQuantity, 0 AS SRate, Date
                              FROM            RightShare
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT        OwnerId, CompanyId, 0 AS PQuantity, 0 AS PRate, Quantity AS SQuantity, RatePerShare AS SRate, Date
                              FROM            Sales) AS sq INNER JOIN
                             Owner AS o ON sq.OwnerId = o.OwnerId INNER JOIN
                             Company AS c ON sq.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
    WHERE        (sq.OwnerId = @Param1) AND (CONVERT(DATE, sq.Date, 111) BETWEEN @Param2 AND  @Param3)
    GROUP BY sq.CompanyId, c.Name, o.Name, o.OwnerId
```

Comment: This popped out at me "/ SUM(nullif(sq.PQuantity,0)"

Comment: i've edited the question, I used nullif to avoid this situation, but its not giving correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `HAVING SUM(sq.PQuantity) > 0` to the bottom of your query.

Comment: it works dude, thanks a lot :) going to accept your answer in 3 minutes :D